# Media Query below 768px not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, media-queries

I am writing a media query for a web-page and managed to write media queries for 768 and below. But it doesn't work properly. I want to capture the portrait views of most of the mobiles( iphone4, iphone5,iphone3,asus galaxy 7,samsung galaxy sII, samsung galaxy s3 ) which is 320px. The webpage I created was working for 768px and above but not working for media query below 768px

```
@media (min-width:481px) and (max-width:768px) {
        .navbar-brand{
    margin-left: 80px;

        }}

      @media (min-width: 768px){ 
           .navbar-brand{
    margin-left: 100px;

    }
         @media (min-width: 991px){ 
        .navbar-brand{
    margin-left: 150px;

        }}
```

Here in this example margin left property working very well on min-width: 768px and min-width:991px but not working on @media (min-width:481px) and (max-width:768px).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a curly bracket to close of your media query for `min-width: 768px`. Here's the final code with formatting to more easily see it.

```
@media (min-width:481px) and (max-width:768px) {
    .navbar-brand {
        margin-left: 80px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-brand {
        margin-left: 100px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 991px) {
    .navbar-brand{
        margin-left: 150px;
    }
}
```

For capturing screensizes that is 320px with a specific margin you can either remove `(min-width:481px) and` from your first media query if the same styling should apply or add a media query specific for that case:

```
@media (max-width: 320px) {
    .classname {
        enter some code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please take a look and confirm below media queries with updated code.**

```
      @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { 
        .navbar-brand {
           margin-left: 100px;
         }
      }

      @media only screen (min-width: 481px) and (max-width:767px) {
        .navbar-brand {
           margin-left: 80px;
         }
      }
```